# How do you pass data source to a local report when you use Navigation-> Go to report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reporting

We are moving from Reporting Services remote to local,for this i've been converting the rdl files to rdlc successfully and changing the reportviewers to local processing and passing the data source via code like this:

```
  ReportDataSource data = new ReportDataSource("PARAGAINSA", new InventarioRptCs().Selecciona_Saldos_Articulo(locid,
            BodId,depid,FamId,NBid,imId,desde,hasta));
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(data);
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Works great, i've also encounter some reports that have some subreports to pass the data source to the sub reports i've been doing it like this:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SubReporteHandler);

 private void SubReporteHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    int im_id =  Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters[1].Values[0].ToString());
    int loc_id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters[0].Values[0]);
    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("PARAGAINSA", new InventarioRptCs().Selecciona_Saldos_Articulo_Det(loc_id,im_id)));
}
```

it also worked great, so i happily continue until i find a Report that has a subreport and the subreport has this in one of the fields: [image]

when i click on the field that acts as the navigation link to the other report i get this 
**A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'datasource'.**

so my question is: is there anyway i can pass the data source to the report inside the sub report that is been call via navigation -> go to report? if so how?

I am using VS 2013, with SQL server 2012

Thank you for reading, pardon my english not my first languague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i was not able to find another way to solve this i did the following to try and simulate the navigation between reports that is only available(to my knowledge) in processing mode remote,

First in the rdlc file i added 'Ver mas informacion' in the title property of the column that was acting as the link to the other report and set the Color to blue to give it a link style

[image: step]

i had to add the tooltip(rendes to title attribute) because i was not able to find another way to be able to select those specific cells that i wanted

then a css style to set the Cursor to pointer

```
 [title="Ver mas informacion"] {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

then a script using jquery to handle the click event geting the values that i need as a parameter to the other report, navigate to the other report and pass the parameter via URL

```
 $(window).load(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '[title="Ver mas informacion"]', function () {
            var locId = $('[id$="ddLocal"]').val();
            var Fecha = $(this).parent().parent()[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            var TT_Id = $(this).parent().parent()[0].childNodes[9].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            var Ap_Id = $(this).parent().parent()[0].childNodes[10].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            window.open(window.location.origin + config.base + '/Reportes/RptSubViewer.aspx?Sub=Doc&Loc=' + locId + '&Fecha=' + Fecha + '&AP=' + Ap_Id + '&TT_Id=' + TT_Id);
        });

    });
```

then over the other webform i only added a reportviewer and on the code behind

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Sub"] == "Doc")
        {
            string _loc = Request.QueryString["Loc"];
            string _fecha = Request.QueryString["Fecha"];
            string _Ap_Id = Request.QueryString["AP"];
            string _TT_Id = Request.QueryString["TT_Id"];
            int loc_id = 0, TT_id = 0, Ap_Id = 0;
            CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            DateTime Fecha = DateTime.Now;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_loc))
                loc_id = Convert.ToInt32(_loc);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fecha))
                Fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(_fecha,"dd/MMM/yyyy",provider);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Ap_Id))
                Ap_Id = Convert.ToInt32(_Ap_Id);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_TT_Id))
                TT_id = Convert.ToInt32(_TT_Id);

            if (TT_id == 14 || TT_id == 15 || TT_id == 21)
            {

                List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
                paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("LocId", _loc));
                paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("Fecha", Fecha.ToShortDateString()));
                paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("TT_Id", _TT_Id));
                paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("TT_Doc", _Ap_Id));
                ReportDataSource data = new ReportDataSource("ARACLDS", new InventarioRptCs().Selecciona_Saldos_Articulo_Doc(loc_id, Fecha, TT_id, Ap_Id).ToList());
                RVSubNav.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Rdlcs\\ReporteKardexDoc.rdlc";
                RVSubNav.Visible = true;
                RVSubNav.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList);
                RVSubNav.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                RVSubNav.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(data);
                RVSubNav.LocalReport.Refresh();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

not sure if the best way but it got the job done